# Is there any command line operating system which prioritizes user-friendliness over programming power?

Tags: command-line

Has anyone designed a command line operating system, with some standard applications like mail and Lynx web browser (or other), which is as easy to use as a mainstream commercial OS like MacOS, rather than being a powerful yet complicated tool for programmers?

Why would someone want that? Some people find the command line interface preferable.

The GitHub CLI is a recently developed command line tool that I found had a nice, modern, user-friendly design.

Ideally, it wouldn't be so hard to learn. A lot of command line tools have very dense manual pages with lots of options.

Comment: My gut reaction is "why would you want that? if you want ease of use, use a GUI". Can you expand on the requirements for such a CLI?

Comment: See, IMHO, CLI is always more complicated and difficult to operate than GUI interfaces. You need to have a plenty of experience before you can manage a CLI OS.

Comment: @saaranshgarg CLI interfaces generally give you more fine-grained control over the commands and will expose more commands than the GUI. Additional functionality comes at the cost of complexity.

Comment: Yes, Agreed @doneal24. CLI reveals the real power of a computer

Comment: A lot of options doesn't mean you m.u.s.t. use them all, always. I consider myself quite confident in e.g. Bash, even though I seldom use more than a few options of the usual commands. The knowledge increases with time as you begin, and persist, using the shell (CLI). I often find GUI solutions coarse and clunky.

Comment: This really feels like a case of "roll your own" to me. Or rather, collect a bunch of tools you like (and write some simple utility scripts for yourself).

Comment: I feel you on that